# Primefaces push

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use 'primefaces push' in my web application to receive notifications.

I would like that a user could receive notifications depending on the groups he belongs to. Every user can belong to several groups, for example:

- User X belongs to Group A and B.
- User Y begong to Group A, C and D.
- User Z belong to Group B and C.

When a user is logged in the web application then this user should subscribe to these notification groups.

My question is how many 'socket' I must create for a user.

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/groupX"  />
```

For example, if a user belongs to two groups, should I dynamically create two socket in the JSF page? Could I just create one socket and use it to receive notifications from different groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are not subsets of one another, you cannot use one generic socket (one channel). Depending on the number of logged in users and/or the number of groups and/or the number of groups a user is a member of, I can see an additional possible solution (besides creating a socket for each group as you already mentioned)

Create a user specific channel for each user and on the server maintain a HashMap with the group name and a list of logged in users that belong to that group. When a message needs to be send to one group, iterate over the list and send it to each individual user

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are suggesting. Thanks